# Combine two intent flags

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an intent which i need to set it, two flags:

FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP -> coz i wanna keep the instance of the current activity in case it' already focused.

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK -> coz i launch the intent outside of it's activity(contexnt.startactivity(..))

problem is that i cant **combine** both of them.. any other solution?

this is my exception:

`06-30 09:12:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2460): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.`

Is this really what you want?

thanks,

ray.

Comment: solution was to use addFlags instead of setFlags, but it still didnt influence.. for example if i currently use browser, and i run another browser intent with those flags, the current page IS being channged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solution was to use addFlags instead of setFlags, but it still didnt influence.. for example if i currently use browser, and i run another browser intent with those flags, the current page IS being channged

Answer (score 8):

The task of combining bitmasks is explained here http://softwareblog.alcedo.com/post/2011/05/31/Using-e2809core2809d-to-combine-A-and-B-Explaining-that-bitmask-thing.aspx in a pretty good way.

Skipping explanations, straight to the case.

Use the OR-operator to combine flags:

```
setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```